# Using Tesseract / Any OCR in PHP / JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine

i wanted to implement a fully working OCR into my webpage , the webpage uses several languages and two of them are js and php i was trying to find ocr which will work **in atleast one** of these languages. (the webpage is being hosted at google appengine)

**what i found** :

**1:** google cloud vision API , i also found their project on github [github link for js implementation of cloud vision api](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/js) the code which is there doesnot work also , it doesnot output the text and it also doesnot output any errors , i have no idea why it doesnot communicate i did everything i should (there are steps that you should follow)

**2:** i also found tesseract ocr which is wrapper for tesseract ocr engine i found website but the 5 line sample after copying and linkind the js source file doesnot do anything there is no documentation at all. [tesseract ocr wrapper for javascript link to webpage](http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/)

**3:** i also found tesseract ocr wrapper in php from user thiagoalessio on github (i cant post more than 2 link) but since im running google appengine hosting , i have no idea how should i implement it into the appengine project , maybe this one will work ? can someone help me ?

***thanks***

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the JavaScript client implementation, but we do have support for this in PHP:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/v0.6.0/vision/visionclient

And in node.js:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/0.38.3/vision

And here's an example of it in use with node.js:
https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/node-cloud-visionator

Hope this helps!